# getting first value of the groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame and want to generate a report on it.

Sample data

```
data = {
 'Date': {0: '2021-01-04 10:45:00',
  1: '2021-01-04 10:45:00',
  2: '2021-01-05 11:15:00',
  3: '2021-01-05 11:15:00',
  4: '2021-01-06 12:15:00',
  5: '2021-01-06 12:15:00'},
 'Action': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'P', 3: 'Q', 4: 'X', 5: 'Y'},
 'Profit': {0: np.NaN, 1: -2637.93, 2: np.NaN, 3: 11008.4, 4: np.NaN, 5: -2977.49},
 }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My normal move is to make a function that will handle all the calculations like this.

```
def magic(x):
    result = {
        'Action' : x['Action'], #Need help here
        'Profit': x['Profit'].sum()
    }
    return pd.Series(result)

df = df.groupby(['Date']).apply(magic)
```

**What I want to happen:**

The Action column should contain the first value of the group.

Wanted output:

```
Date                | Action     | Profit
2021-01-04 10:45:00 |A           |-2637.93
2021-01-05 11:15:00 |P           |11008.40
2021-01-06 12:15:00 |X           |-2977.49
```

Actual output:

```
Date                | Action                                | Profit
2021-01-04 10:45:00 |0 A 1 B Name: Action, dtype: object    |-2637.93
2021-01-05 11:15:00 |2 P 3 Q Name: Action, dtype: object    |11008.40
2021-01-06 12:15:00 |4 X 5 Y Name: Action, dtype: object    |-2977.49
```

My actual function will have more columns so it'll be preferred to have all the operations done inside the magic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If magic function count new columns from multiple input columns then `agg` is not possible use.

Then select first value by indexing:

```
def magic(x):
result = {
    'Action' : x['Action'].iat[0]
    'Profit': x['Profit'].sum()
}
return pd.Series(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to call the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) method on `Action`:

```
out = df.groupby('Date').agg({'Action': 'first', 'Profit': 'sum'})
```

Output:

```
                    Action    Profit
Date                                
2021-01-04 10:45:00      A  -2637.93
2021-01-05 11:15:00      P  11008.40
2021-01-06 12:15:00      X  -2977.49
```

Comment: If I use it like this, will I be able to add other columns as I would add them inside a function, because other columns require calculations that are not as simple as 'sum'

Comment: @Charizard_knows_to_code you could call a lambda that does the jobs you want for those columns. The idea is to use the vectorized operations wherever possible instead of `apply`; but there are use cases where it's not possible of course; also see jezrael's answer.